# How to get the Entity property from which an average is taken in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data

I've fetched some values from my `CoreData Entity`, `Averaged` and `GroupedBy` `date` the results. The query works great. Now... I've want to know the `dates` from which those results come from. The output shown is from the raw result. How could I make my query also spit out the `date`/`GroupBy value` `(given that my GroupBy criteria is date)` from which those averages where taken from

**The output**

```
(
        {
        averageWeight = 36;
    },
        {
        averageWeight = 22;
    }
)
```

**The Code:**

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"ExerciseData" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    // Specify that the request should return dictionaries.
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

    // Create an expression for the key path.
    NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"weight"];

    // Create an expression to represent the function you want to apply
    NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"average:"
                                                         arguments:@[keyPathExpression]];

    // Create an expression description using the minExpression and returning a date.
    NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];

    // The name is the key that will be used in the dictionary for the return value.
    [expressionDescription setName:@"averageWeight"];
    [expressionDescription setExpression:expression];
    [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType]; // For example, NSDateAttributeType

    // Set the request's properties to fetch just the property represented by the expressions.
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:@[expressionDescription]];
    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"exercise == %@",exercise];
    [request setPropertiesToGroupBy:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"date"]];
    // Execute the fetch.
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",objects);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add "date" as another property to fetch:

```
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[expressionDescription, @"date"]];
```